# Using ssl_verifypeer = FALSE in a CRAN pkg?

Tags: r, ssl, curl, cran, httr

I have an API package on CRAN that provides an interface with a United Nations DB ([link](https://comtrade.un.org/data/) to UN site), it's built using httr, which uses the curl package. I discovered yesterday that the core functions of my package were no longer working properly on Windows machines, they all fail with the error message:

`Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates`

Which basically means there's a CA certificate issue preventing curl from completing the connection. After looking into this a bit, I believe the UN site hosting the DB is the issue, its SSL certificate is invalid per ssldecoder (see this [link](https://ssldecoder.org/?host=comtrade.un.org&port=&csr=&s=)).

One easy fix to circumvent this issue is to add param `ssl_verifypeer = FALSE` to all calls to `httr::GET()`. However this is not an ideal solution for security reasons, since it bascially tells curl to make the connection regardless of the validity of the site's certificate.

My question is, what is the consensus on using this parameter within a CRAN package? Keeping in mind that the UN website is (presumably) safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html:

> Get a CA certificate that can verify the remote server and use the proper option to point out this CA cert for verification when connecting. For `libcurl` hackers: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH, capath)`;

In R `curl` options, that's `capath`.

You can get recent versions of those here https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html provided you trust the main cURL site.

`cacert.pem` === `ca-bundle.crt` if you happen to see references to both/either.

If updated CA files still cause the issue then you're doing a disservice to the user by having them think they're OK by just passing `FALSE` to your functions.

I have no idea what harm data comtrade data integrity loss/manipulation would cause folks. But beyond that, a flagged cert cld also be a sign to the user of MITM. Either way, you should think twice about being an enabler.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @hrbrmstr. I have emailed CRAN to let them know what's going on and suggested they take the package down until the issues can be sorted out. I've also filed a bug report on the UN Comtrade website, giving them a heads up of what I've found and asking if they've recently changed their SSL certificates. One last question, I'm still able to pull CSV data from the site with read.csv, and json data with the rjson pkg...does this just mean that these options are inherently less secure than httr/curl (and thus I should not rely on them)?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about consensus, but [Hadley writes](https://github.com/skardhamar/rga/issues/3#issuecomment-13835559):

> You should NEVER use ssl.verifypeer = FALSE as a default, unless you don't want to know when your security has been compromised.

That said, [I have seen packages](https://github.com/duncantl/RGoogleDocs/blob/master/R/auth.R) using the option by default.

The question is: without a valid certificate, how do you know that the UN website has **not** been compromised?

I would suggest flagging the issue clearly at the top of the package documentation and indicating that it's the users responsibility to set the option. And hoping that the hosting service sorts out its certificate soon.

Comment: @neifws Thanks for the input and the links. Regarding your question, I hadn't considered that the UN site might be compromised. I like your potential solution as a last resort. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that it is compromised, nor that it isn't. I guess the issue is that **if** it were, you would not want to provide an insecure option by default. If an individual user wishes to proceed, that's their decision.

Comment: Not so sure putting the onus on the user == an acceptable answer.

Comment: It's a better alternative than silently enabling by default. If it's **very** clearly documented, I don't see it as "unacceptable".

Comment: Most users have no idea what it means or the threat/risk involved.